# $\overline{E}$ is the smallest subset of X

Tags: general-topology

> [image]

I follow up to "There is a point $x^\prime\in \overline{E} \cap U_x$." But, I am struggling to understand the next sentence "Therefore every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $E$ and hence $x \in \overline{E}$".

Specifically, I agree that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $E$. But, how does it lead to $x \in \overline{E}$?

I really appreciate if you elaborate on this.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the definition of $\overline{E}$ at this point in the book is "the set of elements $x\in X$ such that any neighbourhood of $x$ contains an element of $E$". Then, the conclusion $x\in \overline{E}$ is by very definition. If I stated a different definition, please let me know.

Comment: Consider balls $B(x,\delta_n)$,($\delta_n \to 0$), each contains a point in $E$, hence $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

Comment: " I agree that every neighborhood of x contains a point of E". Then you agree that $x$ is a point of closure.  $\overline E$ is, I assume, $E \cup \{$points of closure of $E\}$ so $x \in . \{$points of closure of $E\}\subset \overline E$

Comment: @Suzet  "I am pretty sure that the definition of E¯¯¯¯ at this point in the book is "the set of elements x∈X such that any neighbourhood of x contains an element of E"."  Actually I assumed a set $E'$ was that set and $\overline E = E \cup E'$.  So $x \in E' \subset E\cup E' = \overline E$.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  You meant Any neighborhood of $X$ contains *some* point of E possibly if $x$ is the only such point of E.  ... then I guess that would be $\overline E = E \cup $ {closure points of E}. And that'd be the same thing as what I said.  Never mind.

Comment: Oh double, never mind.  Suzet's definitions are clearly the ones this book uses.  The book and suzets conclusion is equivalent to mine but the definitions the book uses are slightly different than mine.  (I.e. "points of closure" means either a point of E or a limit point of E)